# How to change 'select an option' text from 'WooCommerce Product Add-ons' plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i'm using the woocommerce product Add-ons plugin and **i want to change** the default value that appears on dropdowns that says '**select an option**':

[image]

I managed to find all other english texts in the plugins editor and changed them but this single line is bugging me because i can't seem to find where it is initialized.

**EDIT**

This is the exact plugin i'm using:

[Woocommerce product Add-Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/?utm_source=product&utm_medium=upsell&utm_campaign=wcaddons)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to mention exactly which plugin you are using - there seem to be a few with a name like "Product add-ons". And just a thought - have you tried searching all the plug in files for "Select an option", maybe it's hardcoded in as a `placeholder` or something somewhere?

Comment: Assuming you have the same plugin as I do, the line 'Select an option...' is found in 2 places: the file `select.php` and the translation file `woocommerce-product-addons.pot`. Changing those might work for you.

Comment: @samiles ... I found it in the select.php file, thanks so much.. Put it up as answer and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be to add a line on your functions.php child theme where you can change text:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_product_variation_message', 10, 3 );
function customizing_product_variation_message( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
if ($untranslated_text == 'Select an option...') {
    $translated_text = __( 'ENTER HERE THE NEW TEXT', $domain );
}
return $translated_text;
}
```

Bear in mind that you might need to remove the ... at the end of the "Select an option" text.

Hope that helps

Comment: Much better approach than editing the core plugin, which would then revert back on updates.

Comment: I was having the same question and since this text is inserted via JavaScript  I was trying to change it with JavaScript, but this works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and place it into functions.php

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_product_variation_message', 10, 3 );
function customizing_product_variation_message( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
if ($untranslated_text == 'Select an option...') {
    $translated_text = __( 'PAST YOUR TEXT HERE', $domain );
}
    if ($untranslated_text == 'None') {
    $translated_text = __( 'PAST YOUR TEXT HERE', $domain );
}
return $translated_text;
}
```